# Why different internet display totally different website with the same URL?

Tags: web, dns, server, ping

This is really weird to me, I just registered a domain yesterday and I updated the DNS settings to my own server. And this happened: At home, using my WiFi, the URL display me the "Your domain is registered blah blah blah" page, and I asked my friends to open the URL it's already directed to where it suppose to be. I have used pingdom to get a screenshot and it worked. I tried to use the LTE on my phone too, and it worked. But just **on my own WiFi, no matter what device, it is still on the wrong page**. I have restarted everything, and it just won't work.

It's **not** a question about how website display slightly different, it is entirely different page.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "dns propagation", it can take many hours before all dns servers worldwide have picked up a dns change,

Comment: and it is up to 24h..

Comment: @fvu  I have already waited for 13 hrs, I just don't know if I suppose to do anything or just keep waiting. Since many domains I registered before showed up almost instantly after I update DNS, I wonder if this is a technical problem. Thanks and I'll wait.

Comment: For now you can try to change your DNS servers for your connection. Try [opendns](https://www.opendns.com/), these are the ip addresses: 208.67.222.222 · 208.67.220.220. Usually my provider's dns servers are the slowest.

Answer (score 0):

Different ISPs have different DNS caching policies. Whilst most hosting providers and even global dns providers can be quick to refresh their DNS, residential Internet providers may not be. Some can take up to 24 hours and this is shown in the current problem.